# How good does Memgraph scale in terms of the performance?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am evaluating different graph databases and I want to know how good does Memgraph scale in terms of the performance? Are there any benchmarks available that I can see and maybe run by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph is designed to be a high-performance graph database, and it typically outperforms many other graph databases in terms of speed and scalability. More info can be found in [Memgraph FAQ](https://memgraph.com/docs/help-center/faq/memgraph#how-does-memgraph-compare-to-other-graph-databases-regarding-performance). If you head over to [Benchgraph website](https://memgraph.com/benchgraph), you can see the current benchmarks Memgraph vs Neo4j and if you want to spin it by yourself, head over to [benchgraph repository](https://github.com/memgraph/benchgraph). The whitepaper and more information can be found at the [Memgraph website](https://memgraph.com/memgraph-for-neo4j-developers).